# How to enable synctex with Kile and Okular?

Tags: forward-inverse-search, kile, okular

I am using Ubuntu, Kile, and Okular. What are the exact steps to enable and use synctex with that setup?

What I want to achieve is that I open the compiled PDF with Okular (from Kile) and then clicking on a part of the PDF displayed immediately leads me to the corresponding part of the Tex code.